# Number of ways to arrange 4 identical objects in 6 bins.

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to count the number of ways to play 4 indistinguishable objects in 6 bins. Each bin can contain either 0 or 1 object. We can think of this as the number of binary strings of length 6 with exactly four 1's. Thanks!

Comment: Approaching the problem through binary strings is a good idea.  The numbers are sufficiently small that you should be able to list all the possibilities, from which you could then derive a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me draw you 6 bins:

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

now let me give you an example:

```
|x|x|x|_|x|_|
```

and another example:

```
|x|_|x|_|x|x|
```

and another example

```
|x|_|_|x|x|x|
```

in how many ways can you put those x in 6 bins?

Let me sharpen the question: in how many ways can you **choose** 4 items from 6? and here's another nice thing to notice...in how many ways can you **choose** 2 from 6? (hint: same answer)